# IBM MQ(7.0.1.9) throws NumberFormatException on Weblogic startup

Tags: jms, weblogic, ibm-mq

I have a feature through which i am trying to post a message onto JMS topic.This feature is exposed as rest endpoint and is deployed in weblogic server.However , i face an issue which is onetime alone on weblogic startup. When i try to do an integration testing against the rest endpoint, it throws the following exception when the in the code snippet where session is trying to get created.

I have used IBM MQ Jars for JMS integration along with classes from Javax extension. (IBM MQ version - 7.0.1.9)

The following is my code snippet and exception thrown while trying to create a connection

```
private Connection createConnection() {
    ombConnectionProperties = loadOmbConnectionProperties();
    if (ombConnectionProperties.size() == 0 || ombConnectionProperties == null) {
        buildBusinessException("Could not load OMB properties from environment resource", ExceptionStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    try {
        initSSL(ombConnectionProperties);
        Hashtable<String, String> initialContextPropertiesMatrix = buildInitialContextPropertiesMatrix(ombConnectionProperties);
        ic = new InitialContext(initialContextPropertiesMatrix);
        if(ombConnectionProperties.getProperty("workflow.omb.queueManager")!=null) {
            if(ic!=null) {
                connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup(ombConnectionProperties.getProperty("workflow.omb.queueManager"));
            }
        }
        if(connectionFactory!=null) {
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        propagateException(e);
    }
    return connection;
}

    private Session createSession() {
    try {
        if(connection!=null) {
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        propagateException(e);
    }
    return session;
}


    private Hashtable<String, String> buildInitialContextPropertiesMatrix(Properties ombConnectionProperties) {
    Hashtable<String, String> initialContextPropertiesMatrix = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    if (ombConnectionProperties.getProperty("workflow.omb.ldapProviderUrl") != null) {
        initialContextPropertiesMatrix.put(PROVIDER_URL, ombConnectionProperties.getProperty("workflow.omb.ldapProviderUrl"));
    }
    initialContextPropertiesMatrix.put(INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    initialContextPropertiesMatrix.put(SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    if (ombConnectionProperties.getProperty("workflow.omb.ldapPrincipal") != null) {
        initialContextPropertiesMatrix.put(SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ombConnectionProperties.getProperty("workflow.omb.ldapPrincipal"));
    }
    if (ombConnectionProperties.getProperty("workflow.omb.ldapCredential") != null) {
        initialContextPropertiesMatrix.put(SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, ombConnectionProperties.getProperty("workflow.omb.ldapCredential"));
    }
    return initialContextPropertiesMatrix;
}

    public void publishWorkflowControlMessage(String workflowName, String action) {
    try {
        init();
        String inboundControlMessageXML = buildWorkflowControlMessageXML(workflowName, action);
        Destination destination = null;
        if (ombConnectionProperties.getProperty("workflow.omb.topicName") != null) {
            destination = (Destination) ic.lookup("cn=" + ombConnectionProperties.getProperty("workflow.omb.topicName"));
        }
        MessageProducer producer;
        producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(inboundControlMessageXML);
        producer.send(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        propagateException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if(session!=null){
                session.close();
            }
            if(connection!=null){
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            LOG.error("Exception Occured while closing the OMB connection", e);
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception occured while trying to close the OMB connection", e);
        }
    }
}

workflow.omb.ldapProviderUrl =  ldap://esdqa.csfb.net/ou=MQ,ou=Services,dc=csfb,dc=CS-Group,dc=com
workflow.omb.ldapPrincipal = uid=MQRDP,ou=People,o=Administrators,dc=CS- Group,dc=com
workflow.omb.ldapCredentials = aGMk643R
workflow.omb.queueManager = cn=USTCMN01_CF
workflow.omb.topicName = EDM.BIRS.RDP.ONEPPM.TO_RDA
workflow.omb.certificate.url = properties//jks//test//keystore.jks
workflow.omb.certificate.password = rFzv0UOS
```

P.S: The issue is seen only when i try to connect to JMS at the server startup.When i try for second time it works fine and from then on there are no issues and i am able to post message to the topic.I have no idea whats going wrong.However , when I execute this program as a standalone client  it works fine.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:417)
at java.lang.Short.parseShort(Short.java:120)
at java.lang.Short.valueOf(Short.java:153)
at java.lang.Short.valueOf(Short.java:178)
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsReadablePropertyContextImpl.parseShort(JmsReadablePropertyContextImpl.java:752)
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsReadablePropertyContextImpl.getShortProperty(JmsReadablePropertyContextImpl.java:326)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.WMQPropertyContext.getShortProperty(WMQPropertyContext.java:360)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.<init>(WMQSession.java:311)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.createSession(WMQConnection.java:980)
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionImpl.createSession(JmsConnectionImpl.java:572)
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.createSession(MQConnection.java:339)
```

Am adding the properties in the connection object which I evaluated in debug bug. When I invoke the call the very first time the size of the object is 77 and when I invoke the call again then the size is increased to 78 which resolves it and it was the property "XMSC_ADMIN_OBJECT_TYPE" which is missing in the initial connection object. I am pasting the entire list below

```
0 = {HashMap$Entry@18264} "XMSC_WMQ_HEADER_COMP" -> " size = 1"
1 = {HashMap$Entry@18265} "wildcardFormat" -> "0"
2 = {HashMap$Entry@18266} "XMSC_WMQ_BROKER_PUBQ" -> "SYSTEM.BROKER.DEFAULT.STREAM"
3 = {HashMap$Entry@18267} "XMSC_WMQ_CONNECTION_TAG" -> 
4 = {HashMap$Entry@18268} "XMSC_WMQ_BROKER_SUBQ" -> "SYSTEM.JMS.ND.SUBSCRIBER.QUEUE"
5 = {HashMap$Entry@18269} "XMSC_WMQ_SHARE_CONV_ALLOWED" -> "1"
6 = {HashMap$Entry@18270} "XMSC_WMQ_SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY" -> "null"
7 = {HashMap$Entry@18271} "multicast" -> "0"
8 = {HashMap$Entry@18272} "brokerVersion" -> "-1"
9 = {HashMap$Entry@18273} "XMSC_WMQ_MESSAGE_SELECTION" -> "0"
10 = {HashMap$Entry@18274} "XMSC_WMQ_CLEANUP_LEVEL" -> "1"
11 = {HashMap$Entry@18275} "XMSC_CLIENT_ID" -> "null"
12 = {HashMap$Entry@18276} "XMSC_WMQ_SUBSCRIPTION_STORE" -> "1"
13 = {HashMap$Entry@18277} "XMSC_WMQ_RECEIVE_EXIT" -> "null"
14 = {HashMap$Entry@18278} "XMSC_WMQ_SSL_CERT_STORES_COL" -> "null"
15 = {HashMap$Entry@18279} "XMSC_WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT" -> "1800"
16 = {HashMap$Entry@18280} "XMSC_WMQ_RECEIVE_EXIT_INIT" -> "null"
17 = {HashMap$Entry@18281} "XMSC_WMQ_TEMP_TOPIC_PREFIX" -> 
18 = {HashMap$Entry@18282} "XMSC_WMQ_CONNECT_OPTIONS" -> "0"
19 = {HashMap$Entry@18283} "XMSC_WMQ_MAP_NAME_STYLE" -> "true"
20 = {HashMap$Entry@18284} "XMSC_WMQ_MSG_BATCH_SIZE" -> "10"
21 = {HashMap$Entry@18285} "XMSC_WMQ_USE_CONNECTION_POOLING" -> "true"
22 = {HashMap$Entry@18286} "XMSC_WMQ_TARGET_CLIENT_MATCHING" -> "true"
23 = {HashMap$Entry@18287} "XMSC_USERID" -> 
24 = {HashMap$Entry@18288} "XMSC_WMQ_SPARSE_SUBSCRIPTIONS" -> "false"
25 = {HashMap$Entry@18289} "XMSC_WMQ_MSG_COMP" -> " size = 1"
26 = {HashMap$Entry@18290} "XMSC_WMQ_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE" -> "1000"
27 = {HashMap$Entry@18291} "XMSC_WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE" -> "1"
28 = {HashMap$Entry@18292} "XMSC_WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS" -> "0"
29 = {HashMap$Entry@18293} "XMSC_WMQ_CHANNEL" -> "USTCMN01_CLS_01"
30 = {HashMap$Entry@18294} "XMSC_WMQ_TEMP_Q_PREFIX" -> 
31 = {HashMap$Entry@18295} "XMSC_WMQ_RECEIVE_ISOLATION" -> "0"
32 = {HashMap$Entry@18296} "XMSC_WMQ_POLLING_INTERVAL" -> "5000"
33 = {HashMap$Entry@18297} "XMSC_CONNECTION_TYPE" -> "1"
34 = {HashMap$Entry@18298} "XMSC_WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER" -> "USTCMN01"
35 = {HashMap$Entry@18299} "XMSC_WMQ_PROCESS_DURATION" -> "0"
36 = {HashMap$Entry@18300} "XMSC_WMQ_CLONE_SUPPORT" -> "0"
37 = {HashMap$Entry@18301} "XMSC_WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SUITE"   
..............
........
48 = {HashMap$Entry@18312} "XMSC_ADMIN_OBJECT_TYPE" -> "20"
..........
............
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your code.

Comment: @Shashi I have added the code now. Please let me know whether this will suffice